# Ideas for Android Securty Project

Tags: android, security, rsa

I am a student taking a course in Network security.As a part of my coursework I need to do a project on the security side of Android like developing a simple application which involves basic security concepts.

I searched for different ideas which I can implement on Android within a span of 2-3 weeks.I found ideas such as secure sms or mobile antivirus or mobile finder.I am a beginner with the Android development and thus I might require more time to develop these apps(Maybe a month)

Can anyone please suggest some ideas for simple security apps which I can develop within 2-3 weeks?

Thanks,

Ameya

Comment: secure sms would involve SIP and VOIp and server side..you do not have enough time to do that in a 2 week period being only at the beginner stage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I found ideas such as secure sms or mobile antivirus or mobile finder.

I have no idea what "secure sms" is. I have no idea what "mobile finder" is. Since there are no Android viruses at present, you do not even know what an Android virus would look like, and even if you did, you would have no way of stopping one.

> I am a beginner with the Android development and thus I might require more time to develop these apps(Maybe
>   a month)

"mobile antivirus" would require far closer to 100 developer-months than one developer-month.

> Can anyone please suggest some ideas for simple security apps which I can develop within 2-3 weeks?

Create an application that iterates over all other installed applications (using `PackageManager`) and examines the permissions each application requests (using `PackageInfo`). Come up with profiles of sets of permissions that may result in privacy breaches (e.g., `INTERNET` plus `READ_CONTACTS`). Create an activity that displays all the applications in two tabs, one tab for ones with scary permissions, one tab for the rest. Those applications would be in `ListViews`; tapping on one would display the list of permissions for the application plus, in the case of the scary ones, why you think it is scary.

Comment: "Since there are no Android viruses at present" That's obviously not true, maybe there are no big media hypes about them yet.

Comment: @Longpoke: You are welcome to cite evidence of one, then. My point, though, is that I rather doubt the OP has evidence of one, and it is rather difficult to write an anti-virus without a virus.

Comment: +1 for your idea. I might even do that myself, it sounds pretty useful =]

Comment: Thanks a lot CommonsWare!!! Really appreciate it. I guess I can develop much more advanced app than this.So any advanced idea is also welcome such as using Digital Signatures or implementing any other security protocol.

Comment: Secure SMS deals with secure server that generates token to encrypt SMS..usually paired up with secure VOIP..several apps out using the telesecret Sdk apis in the marketplace..